# which one to use - GKE or GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Found this question on one of the sites for GCP:

You have a single binary application that you want to run on Google Cloud Platform. You decided to automatically scale the application based on underlying infrastructure CPU usage. Your organizational policies require you to use virtual machines directly. You need to ensure that the application scaling is operationally efficient and completed as quickly as possible. What should you do?

A. Create a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster, and use horizontal pod autoscaling to scale the application.

B. Create an instance template, and use the template in a managed instance group with autoscaling configured.

C. Create an instance template, and use the template in a managed instance group that scales up and down based on the time of day.

D. Use a set of third-party tools to build automation around scaling the application up and down, based on Stackdriver CPU usage monitoring.

Since it is required to use VM's directly - Answer should be B, correct?
Any reason why A could be the answer?

Comment: There are too few informations. What mean use VM directly? Is it in contrast with physical servers? Is forbid serverless? Is your workload is trigger by HTTP request? What is the required CPU and memory of your workload? What scalability do you need? Scale to 0? scale to N (what is N)? Is container technology is approved by your company?

Answer (score 0):

I will say the answer is B, because it meets the following conditions:
1) Your organizational policies require you to use virtual machines directly
2) automatically scale the application based on underlying infrastructure CPU usage.
3) You need to ensure that the application scaling is operationally efficient and completed as quickly as possible

For A:
It doesn't meet the condition where you are required to use virtual machine directly.

For C: 
It doesn't meet the condition where you need it to autoscaling based on the CPU Usage.

For D:
The instance group template is built-in and it can meet all your requirements. Having 3rd party is complicated and not as efficient as instance group autoscaling settings.